# How does a compiled c executible know how to represent a series of bits at a specific memory address?

Tags: c, compilation

I understand a C variable is replaced with a memory address during compilation and the symbol table with type info does not survive compilation.

I'm trying to understand how data is stored and retrieved (represented) during programming execution. I understand a variable is mapped to a memory address and that my precompiled code designates the type (number of bits and how to read them). But if the type is lost by the time the code is compiled into an executable, how does the machine code (the .exe) know how the size of the data at a specific memory address and how to represent those bits?

I've seen many similar questions asked but the answers are always framed that the CPU doesn't care or know what the series of bits are intended to represent. That, however, isn't exactly what I'm asking. I want to know how the executable program knows the number of bits that are significant and how to read (represent) them if the type (integer, char, double, string, or bit field) is unknown?

Comment: You're under a misconception. The type of the data is not *unknown* to the executable that is running. It's unknown to the operating system and CPU, but not to the code that is executing that is using that data. What exactly do you think that programming does that would somehow forget what the contents of its memory contain and what it is doing with that memory?

Comment: Ken, that is precisely what I am struggling with. If I declare an integer or char or double (or whatever), it is my understanding that the variable is assigned a memory address and the type declaration determines the number of bits that will be read (and represented) in my program.

Comment: The type declaration tells the compiler of your code the number of bits, and that's all the CPU needs to know. Your own code and compiler know that that address stores a variable of a certain type, and that that type is a certain number of bits. All your code needs to know is that the address points to a certain type (int, for instance); the address in high level compilers is contained in a variable, and you know the name of that variable and that it points to storage to an int.

Comment: But where is the type declaration stored in the final exe if the symbol table is gone? How is the type information saved (known by) the .exe if the type information in the symbol table isn't saved somewhere?

Comment: It's not *stored in the final exe*. That's the misconception. What's stored in the final exe are CPU instructions to operate on data, and data to be operated on. The type information is used by the compiler to generate that code and data.

Comment: To clarify, I've been reading about compilation for the past two weeks or so. I've read that the symbol table in the object code does not survive compilation. I figure the .exe file can't operate without type representation, but I can't find how that is stored in the .exe without a symbol table.

Comment: Ahh... so the CPU instruction set includes type information for specific registers? But if that is built into the CPU, how do various languages have different types? Or are those types manipulated by the compiler into a more limited set used by the CPU registers?

Comment: You should look up the instruction set of your CPU.  That is what it does.  Only those binary instruction codes and data types can be handled.  That is all it can do. Anything more complex HAS to be made up from those  building blocks by, say, a compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler generates machine instructions that does specifically what it wants. (This may be done in multiple steps, generating intermediate code in the compiler’s own language, then turning that into assembly language, then assembling that into machine instructions.)

The machine instructions have specific forms, such as:

- Load 32 bits into register 8 from address 1234
- Store 64 bits from register 7 into address 4320.
- Load 32 bits into register 3 from memory 9000 bytes beyond the current program counter.
- Store 8 bits from register 4 into memory 124 bytes beyond the stack pointer.
- Add from register 3 into register 4.
- Compare register 3 to register 4.
- Branch if the last comparison indicating signed greater-than.
- Shift the contents of register 4 right 5 bits (“logically,” filling in zeros).
- Shift the contents of register 4 right 5 bits (“arithmetically,” duplicating the sign bit).

So, if your program is reading a `char` value, the compiler generates an instruction to load 8 bits. If your program is reading an `int` value, the compiler generates an instruction to load 32 bits (presuming `int` is 32 bits in your C implementation).

In many instructions, the processor does not need to know what the data type is. Loading 32 bits is loading 32 bits regardless of whether those bits are an `int` or a pointer. Even when adding signed or unsigned integers, the bit patterns are designed so that one add instruction works for either signed or unsigned integers.

Some instructions need to know the data type. Signed and unsigned integers cannot be compared with the same instructions. For a signed 32-bit `int`, the bits 0xffffffff represent −1, which is less than 0 (bits 0x00000000), but, for an unsigned `int`, those bits represent 4,294,967,295, which is greater than zero. So, for `x < y`, the compiler generates one instruction if they are signed and a different instruction if they are unsigned. (Actually, there may be one compare instruction for multiple types of data, but it produces multiple bits indicating various possible results, and another instruction tests those bits and branches according to the results. If the compare instruction is not customized to the data type, then the test-and-branch instruction is.)

Comment: Eric, so the compiled machine code replaces the type with size (number of bits) and when more type info is needed beyond the number of bits, the CPU registers are differentiated to handle different types? Where do I go to learn this (or is learning assembler the only real way)?

Comment: @BillMac: No, the CPU registers are not differentiated to handle different types, at least not for integers and pointers, in most processors. As I listed, there are different **instructions** for different operations, not different registers or different indications in registers. There is an instruction for “multiply signed integers from registers 3 and 4 and put result in register 6” and a different instruction for “multiply unsigned integers from registers 3 and 4 and put result in register 6.” The **instruction** says what to do with the data.

Comment: @BillMac: Many processors do have separate registers for floating-point data. Even there, though, the distinction between `float` and `double` (and possibly `long double`) is in the instructions, not in the registers.